# Cocoapods: what is the best way to modify the resources

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using cocoapods to manage third party libraries for my iOS project. The resources (e.g. images) are located in the Pods project. Now if I want to replace some of those resources, for example `bg-addbutton.png` in the snapshot, what would be the best way to do? I'm thinking of replacing the resources directly in the Pods project, but the new resources will be overwritten if I upgrade the libraries later on.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I usually do is forking the 3rd party project (probably on GitHub) and push the changes to my fork. Then, on `Podfile` you just point to your repo:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'MyAwesomeLib', :git => 'https://github.com/myuser/MyAwesomeLib'
```

Comment: This gives me an error `[!] No podspec found ...`. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Found the solution. I have to move my `.podspec` file to the root folder. And you can keep `:git => 'https://github.com/...git'` as it is (pointing to the old repo). Your `:git =>` in your `Podfile` will override it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can move that pod locally to you machine local directory and make changes in that particular pod and install pod from your local path. For perform this you need pod project download from git with **.podspec** file.

- For install pod use below statement.

pod '**PODNAME**', :path => "**LOCAL POD PATH**"

**PODNAME** :- Same aa pod name from you downloaded pod file.
**LOCAL POD PATH** :- Pod directory which contains **.podspec** file.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way in which you can modify the library code/resource and get future updates from the library, all while still maintaining it via cocoapods

[image]
Here is the article explaining it. (written by me)

https://medium.com/@mihirpmehta/how-to-modify-cocoapods-library-within-pods-647d2bf7e1cb